# Firebase Push Notification Registered Users Number is more than actual users

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to learn Push Notifications in iOS and registered my app to firebase with my AuthKey. There is no problem with sending a test notification but even though I'm the only one who uses the app it says "100% of potential users are eligible for this campaign: 7". I didn't get it. I literally just uploaded my AuthKey and sended my first test notification.

On another app of mine, there are 5-8 users but Firebase says "100% of potential users are eligible for this campaign: 46" this time. How is this possible?